# Snowflake changing varchar field to date - getting error 'Can't parse '1/7/2022' as date with format 'MM/DD/YYY'

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column of VARCHAR format that comes in as 'MM/DD/YYYY 0:00'. I've done a replace 'DATEFROM = REPLACE(DATEFROM,' 0:00','') ' to get rid of the useless time portion.

Then I was trying 'TO_DATE(DATEFROM::VARCHAR, 'MM/DD/YYYY')' but I get the error 'Can't parse '1/7/2022' as date with format 'MM/DD/YYYY''.

I've tried without the ::VARCHAR which gives the same error. I've also tried TRY_TO_DATE which put null into the field.

I've also tried a Trim on the DATEFROM column with the same error occurring.

While I'd like something that would take the 'MM/DD/YYYY 0:00' format and allow me to get to 'YYYY-MM_DD' but I think that might be a stretch.

Edit: sorry about the typo and not seeing the responses sooner, the year should be YYYY not 3
I'll try the suggestions.

Comment: "*I have a column of VARCHAR format that comes in as 'MM/DD/YYY 0:00*" `1/7/2022` is not `MM/DD/YYYY` format. Can you try to expand on how you came to the conclusion otherwise? Have you read [the descriptions for each of the date formatting elements for Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#date-and-time-formats)? `MM` and `DD` explicitly stand-in for **two** digit representations of the month and day, respectively; you've got single digits based on your example.

Comment: @esqew the actual problem is the 3 `Y` is meaningless, as per the doc's you point to (except in the INTERVAL command, which this is not), and snowflake does not mind lead zero being present or not.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `Y` in your year. should be 4

I have used the `TRY_` form of the parser to avoid the error message, but the result show NULL in snowflake, thus parsing fails.

The triple YYY form is only valid in the INTERVAL command, and this is not INTERVAL.

thus:

```
SELECT
    '1/7/2022' as d1,
    '01/07/2022' as d2,
    TRY_TO_DATE(d1, 'MM/DD/YYY'),    
    TRY_TO_DATE(d2, 'MM/DD/YYY'),
    TRY_TO_DATE(d1, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),    
    TRY_TO_DATE(d2, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

gives:

| D1 | D2 | TRY_TO_DATE(D1, 'MM/DD/YYY') | TRY_TO_DATE(D2, 'MM/DD/YYY') | TRY_TO_DATE(D1, 'MM/DD/YYYY') | TRY_TO_DATE(D2, 'MM/DD/YYYY') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/7/2022 | 01/07/2022 |  |  | 2022-01-07 | 2022-01-07 |

Answer (score 1):

If the year is formatted as `YYY` and all the dates are from year 2000 and after, you could pre-pend the year part with `2` to make it `YYYY` then use `split_part` to get just the date portion before casting it to date using `try_to_date`.

```
 select try_to_date(split_part(insert('01/31/021 0:00',7,0,'2'),' ',1))
```